# If $TS=ST$, then $S=\alpha T+\beta$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ be a non-scalar matrix.

> If $S=\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$ be such that $TS=ST$. Why there exists $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}$ such that
>   $$S=\alpha T+\beta I\;?$$

Note that $TS-ST=0$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix}bg-fc & af+bh-eb-fd\\
ce+dg-ga-hc & fc-bg\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
This implies that
$$\begin{cases}
bg-fc = 0,\\
af+bh-eb-fd = 0,\\
ce+dg-ga-hc = 0,\\
fc-bg = 0.
\end{cases}$$
Since $T$ is non scalar, then $b\neq 0$ or $c\neq 0$ or $a\neq d$. However, I cannot find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Dear professor. According to Lemaa 2.3 this result works only when $\text{dim}(H)=2$ (please see https://books.google.tn/books?id=lJbXcjpY4QsC&pg=PA75&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false ) I find contradiction between this result and the provided answer. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I'm Ok. The problem is his comment he says:''The proof works in every vector space on any field K.''

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT. We assume that $T\in M_2(K)$, where $K$ is
a field. $C(T)=\{S\in M_2(K);TS=ST\}$ is a vector space containing $\{I,T\}$, that are linearly independent; then it suffices to show that $dim(C(A))\leq 2$, that is, the entries of such a matrix $S=\begin{pmatrix}p&q\\r&s\end{pmatrix}$ depend at most on $2$ parameters.

$\textbf{Proof}$.  There is a vector $u$ s.t. $\{u,Tu\}$ is a basis of $K^2$; otherwise, let $v,w$ be a basis of $K^2$; one has $Tv=av,Tw=bw,T(v+w)=c(v+w)$, that implies that $T=aI$, a contradiction.

In the basis $\{u,Tu\}$, $T$ becomes $\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&b\end{pmatrix}$ and

$(TS)_{1,1}=(ST)_{1,1},(TS)_{2,1}=(ST)_{2,1}$ iff

$q=ar,p=-br+s$; finally, the entries of $S$ depend at most on the $2$ parameters $r,s$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you don't proceed as my attempt. Please why $T(Tu))=au+bTu$?

Comment: Please have you seen my question ? Thanks

Comment: I just read it. $a,b$ exist because  $u,Tu$ is a basis. Note also that the proof works on every field $K$ and not only over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think that you used $a$ and $b$ in my question. I think also that the proof work in an arbitrary Hilbert space such that its dimension is 2.  Do you agree with me?

Comment: The proof works in every vector space on any field $K$. In particular, $K$ does not need to contain the eigenvalues of $A$. Do you understand why $u$ exists ?

Comment: I think you mix everything; if you want to talk about another topic, then ask another question in a new file.

Comment: Now, my only problem is that $T$ should be in $M_2(K)$ and not in $M_n(K)$.

Comment: Of course, $n=2$; I wrote too fast.